# Use spring security with cxf on karaf - issue with custom filter

Tags: spring-security, cxf, apache-karaf

I'm currently trying to use spring-security (hmac authentication and authorisation) on a cxf REST service, deployed as a bundle in Karaf. (karaf 2.3, cxf 2.7.6 and spring security 3.1.4)
My problem is that I always get a

```
 org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

whenever I try to reach a method. Apparently, I can't get the filter chain to work Maybe linked to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DOSGI-183, as I have this in my spring security logs:

```
Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class[org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, <hmacAuthenticationFilter>, order = 800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2000]
```

Anyway, here is my code:

First I got in a bundle A the authenticationFilter and authenticationProvider, respectively extending  AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.
The filter is exposed as osgi:service, as is the authenticationManager built around the provider

```
 <security:authentication-manager alias="defaultAuthenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="hmacAuthProvider"/>    
</security:authentication-manager>
<osgi:service ref="hmacAuthenticationFilter" interface="com.security.auth.IHmacAuthenticationFilter"/>
<osgi:service ref="defaultAuthenticationManager" interface="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager"/>
```

This is where the logic authentication and authorization logic is.

Now the service :
A simple ressource

```
@Path("test")
public class PocRessource {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("m1")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_M1')")
public String m1() {
    return "calling m - 1";
}
```

And the spring  applicationContext

```
<beans  --schema goes here --
default-lazy-init="false">
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.security.webservice"/>
<osgi:reference id="hmacAuthenticationFilter" interface="com.security.auth.IHmacAuthenticationFilter"/>
 <osgi:reference id="authenticationManager" interface="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager"/>

<bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
<bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
<bean id="pocRessource" class="com.security.webservice.PocRessource"/>
<bean id="forbiddenEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="forbiddenEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"
    create-session="never" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="hmacAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
</security:http>
<jaxrs:server id="pocsecurityWS" address="/pocs/security">
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
         <ref bean="logInbound"/>
     </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
     <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
     </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <ref bean="pocRessource"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

The bundle is generated via maven

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
                            <configuration>
                <supportedProjectTypes>
                  <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                  <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                  <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                </supportedProjectTypes>
                <instructions>
                      <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                      <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                      <Web-FilterMappings>springSecurityFilterChain;url-patterns:="/*"</Web-FilterMappings> 
                  </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after days trying to get it work, I managed to do that using .... Jersey ! Apparently, the javax.servlet.Filter way is not the way for CXF. I think I'll have to put my logic in a AbstractPhaseInterceptor . Can anyone confirm that ? I'll try to implement one

For those interested, here is what I did :

- first use a WAB (war packaging in the pom, then using the mavne bundle plugin. Be careful to put all dependencies with the  "provided" scope)

  org.apache.felix
              maven-bundle-plugin
              true

  ```
          <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>manifest</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
        </executions>

          <configuration>
              <supportedProjectTypes>
                <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
              </supportedProjectTypes>

              <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId} </Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Export-Package/>
                   <Import-Package>
                        javax.servlet;version="[2.5,3)",
                        javax.servlet.http;version="[2.5,3)",
                        org.springframework.core,
                        org.springframework.web.context,
                        org.springframework.web.context.request,
                        org.springframework.security.config,
                        org.springframework.osgi.config,
                        org.springframework.context.config,
                        org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support,
                        com.leguide.backoffice.poc.security.auth,
                        org.springframework.aop,
                        org.springframework.aop.framework,
                        *
                   </Import-Package>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    <Bundle-ClassPath>.,WEB-INF/classes</Bundle-ClassPath>
                    <Embed-Directory>WEB-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Web-ContextPath>/pocsecurity/services</Web-ContextPath>
                    <Webapp-Context>/pocsecurity/services</Webapp-Context>
                    <Web-FilterMappings>springSecurityFilterChain;url-pattern:="/*"</Web-FilterMappings> 
                </instructions>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```
- add a web.xml like :

  ```
  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
      <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
      </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  ```

use the proper bundle in the features xml ( thanks to [Downloading all Jersey OSGi Bundle dependancies automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830255/downloading-all-jersey-osgi-bundle-dependancies-automatically) ) and thats it !

I do have thos logs in my karaf :

```
2013-11-06 11:39:49,247 | DEBUG | services/pocs/m1 | WelcomeFilesFilter               | vice.internal.WelcomeFilesFilter  128 | 82 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 1.1.14 | Path info: null
2013-11-06 11:39:49,247 | DEBUG | services/pocs/m1 | ServletHandler                   | rvlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain 1297 | 65 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.8.v20121106 | call filter springSecurityFilterChain
 2013-11-06 11:39:49,248 | DEBUG | services/pocs/m1 | HmacAuthenticationFilter         | ctAuthenticationProcessingFilter  189 | 84 - org.springframework.web - 3.2.3.RELEASE | Request is to process authentication
2013-11-06 11:39:49,255 | DEBUG | services/pocs/m1 | FilterSecurityInterceptor        | cept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor  215 | 110 - org.springframework.security.core - 3.1.4.RELEASE | Authorization successful
2013-11-06 11:39:49,256 | DEBUG | services/pocs/m1 | SecurityContextPersistenceFilter | SecurityContextPersistenceFilter   97 | 84 - org.springframework.web - 3.2.3.RELEASE | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I do have an issue with jetty returning a 404, but that is something else, I guess

Comment: could you please provide the applicationContext details for above solution? OR if you have full code related to all 3 files, can u send the link?

Comment: sorry, I don't have the code anymore.It simply did not work on karaf. We ended up using came route with the endpoint cxfrs , with a netty/jetty route just before calling the hmac implementation .It goes a bit like this : from netty -> if hmac ok then continue, otherwise send a 401 . More efficient than trying to force a WAR on karaf

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am able to achieve now. I will post the solution later